# What is the bash equivalent of the where cmdlet?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, wildcards

The where cmdlet is something I use in PS quite often- its very convenient.

If I want to get all files with a name starting with "test" I would do this:

```
ls | ?{$_.name -like 'test*'}
```

What is an equally terse way a nix admin would do this in bash? Bash is text not object based obviously so the command would probably be something like:

```
ls | ?{<column#> -like 'test*'}
```

I'm not asking about the ls command (`ls test*` would work, but that's command specific) I'm looking for a terse bash equivalent of how to pipe output through filters like this.

Comment: You're looking for a Linux shell tutorial, and I close-voted as off-topic because of it. But for particularly what you asked, `awk/gawk` will separate lines into fields and allow you to match specific columns, e.g. `ls -lha | awk '$9~/test/'` will print the full `ls -lha` output if field 9 matches "test" (field 9 is the filename here, but I don't know it always will be). See also `cut` if the fields are neatly delimited, and the below answers with `grep`.

Comment: As you note, bash is text-based, not object-based. So, processing filenames using pipes, etc. without precautions can be a bad idea. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return only the files that start with "test":

```
ls | grep '^test'
```

**More examples**:

That will return only lines which contain the word "test". I am using ls -al" instead of "ls" alone to have a 1 line per record result:

```
ls -al | grep "test"
```

This would return any line containing test or word2:

```
ls -al | grep "test\|word2"
```

This would return any line not containing the string "test":

```
ls -al | grep -v "test"
```

If you really want to go by column, you can do like that:

```
ls -al | awk '$9 ~ /^test/'
```

Where $9 would mean column #9 which refers to the filename on my Debian machine, and the following regexp says that it starts with "test". awk separates columns by any run of spaces and/or tabs and/or newlines is treated as a field separator.

Comment: You don't need `ls -l` (ell) to get one filename per line when piping, or redirecting; the multi-column format 
is used only when outputting to a tty, and even there it can also be turned off by `-1` (one). 
`-a` (with a directory operand, or the default of `.`) increases the set of files listed/searched; this may or may not be wanted

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: if you don't like that `ls` stuff even if that is **NOT** command-specific (explained below), use `arr=(); for foo in * [!*]*; do [[ $foo == test* ]] && arr+=("$foo"); done`. This is basically a `arr=list_files.filter((i) -> (i.glob_match('test*'));` as you may write in some other languages.

But if you read on, you will still find out that `ls` is nice and those testing should be skipped by a direct array assignment like `arr=(test*)` (mikeserv made me realize I really need to say this first).

### A quick review on text filtering

Just like others mentions in the comments, Unix shell simply pipes text streams, not object packs. And since the Unix world allows a lot more things in filenames and in a lot of other spaces than Windows, only shell word boundaries is safe. For things like filenames where `\0` is luckily not allowed, you can use it in streams too.

`grep` and friends keeps serving as the basic text filter. It eats in **lines** from stdin or files, matches against a given regex and gives out the matching (or the reverse, `-v`) lines or parts (`-o`) as *stdout*, yet another stream which is still unsafe to use.

This works for newline-separated text like most code and poems, but not for filenames. Filenames can contain newlines and `grep` may see two separate lines for one file from `ls`.

### What globbing looks like to programs in Unix shells

In UNIX shells, wildcards are processed by the shell rather than processed by the target program. This makes things a bit more consistent, and also causes the confusion that makes you think the `test*` part has something to do with `ls`.

Suppose we have the files `test1`, `test2`, `test3`, ls only feels like it was called like this:

```
ls test1 test2 test3
```

It basically knows nothing about what you did to it.

Internally, the `test*` is expanded to shell *words*. And since we have the construct `for varname in [word-list]; do [commands]; done`, we can make things like this:

```
for i in *; do
    if i matches the pattern; then
         do something
    fi # that marks endif
done
```

And there is one thing in bash, `[[`, that performs pattern matching. For a given constuct `[[ lhs == rhs ]]`, bash checks if `lhs` matches the pattern on `rhs`. In our case, we can use `[[ $i == test* ]]` for that `i matches the pattern` part. *This is not available in a minimal POSIX shell, use `case` for that.*

And we need to add some actions to `do something`. In bash, there are arrays:

```
# Arrays doesn't exist in POSIX standard too.
a=() # an empty array, since bash is weak-typed this doesn't mean anything
b=(foo bar baz) # array are assigned with, well, list-of-words.
for i in *; do
    if [ $i == test* ]]; then
         a+=("$i") # quoting avoids some word-splitting and you know what += is
    fi # that marks endif
done
# and here do something to your lonely array, like those described in 
# gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html
```

One more thing here. In Unix systems by convention filenames starting with `.` marks a hidden file and `*` won't include them. `.*` adds them explicitly, but `.` means current dir and `..` means basedir (same as windows) so you want to get rid of them. Using `.[!.]*` works, as it means a dot, a character that is not a dot and any number including zero of characters. This has nothing to do with your `test*` thing, since `test` does not start with `.`.

And for multiple pattern 'or' we can use the `extglob` (um, run `shopt -s extglob` first) thing `@(patt1|patt2)`, or we can wrap the whole thing with a `case` where multiple patterns are allowed, ...

But why do you need such thing? Just use `a=(test*)`. `test*` gives you a list of words if there is a match. For multiple patterns, use `a=(test* tset*)`.

#### But what if glob matching failed?

If a glob matches nothing, it remains as the glob pattern itself in the word list. That looks good for lazy shells users, but not for serious scripters like us.

Luckily there is a `shopt` in bash called `nullglob`, which doesn't put the glob pattern back. Just use `shopt -s nullglob` to enable it first. If you want it portable among other POSIX shells, well, let's go back to for-and-case-filtering.

### How do people get to that `ls` solution

In the following `--` is added in case what you are globbing is not `test*` but `*test*`, and you may get some filename like `-test123` and be recognized as some `ls` options. `--` marks end-of-options [by convention](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html).

```
# So what you need is globbing:
echo test*
# But those are not clear enough since echo only adds spaces between them. Use newlines:
printf '%s\n' test*
# But our screen doesn't have so many lines. Ah, yes, ls can make it into columns:
ls -- test*
# But it lists the contents of the directory test233/. Let's ask it not to:
ls -d -- test*
# Oh, good enough, let's add some color and some pretty type indicator:
ls -dF --color=auto -- test*
```

So for your simple question it goes like: `ls -d test*`. But it is **NOT** for a single command; we are using `ls` only for pretty-printing.

### So is filenames in pipes always stupid?

No. Some programs tried to keep people think they're safe to use by adding/using the `\0` deliminator, like `find -print0` and `xargs -0`. Unluckily it requires [some hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677546/) to let the shells accept `\0`, so..

And there is still a better globbing solution in many shells. `find` walks a directory recursively and conditionally prints the found filenames, and it is often used a way to list files recursively. In bash, we have this:

```
shopt -s globstar
for i in **; do
    try-some-test || continue
    do-something
done
```

Which does the work just well.

But `bash` doesn't provide everything, e.g. it doesn't have neat parallel commands and it's never as fast as native code running. That's why people use other programs like `parallel` do things. Since we have `\0`, well, it's not that bad, and we can use `find -print0` to feed it.

Comment: @mikeserv Because he wants explicit filtering like `(filter (lambda (i) (glob-match i "test*"))  (list-files))`.

Comment: @mikeserv But he wants to see it in action.

Comment: well, from what i understand, the asker wants to reliably prune piped input based on shell glob patterns. you dont do that here - you filter an array into another array in the same shell process. i dont think it fits.

Comment: @mikeserv glob patterns still require good deliminator(s), which is almost unavailable in shell.

Comment: @mikeserv Ther is a problem in your solution, but, well, we both know `nullglob`.

Comment: its not a solution. but if you want it to be: `a=(test*); [ -e "$a" ] || unset a`. anyway, i agree that delimiting output would be the primary problem, but i dont see how not passing it as output solves it.

Comment: @mikeserv If something is silly, avoid it. That's the basic point.

Comment: @mikeserv When it comes to filenames it is silly. With `\0` it's fine, but the shell can't split on `\0` without hacks. Fundamental pains are not a good thing.

Comment: @mikeserv But slashes exist in pathnames…

Comment: nevermind, man. i still dont think it answers the question and instead attempts to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter out all files `beginning` (or more complex) with "test", you can use egrep to apply regex pattern matching.

Searching ls output for files beginning with the letter `D`

```
$ ls |egrep "^D"
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
Dropbox
```

If you don't uses regex, you get this

```
$ ls |grep D
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
Dropbox
README
Vuze Downloads
```

Comment: What's wrong with straightforward globbing: `ls -d D*` for the first example and `ls -d *d*` for the second?

Comment: @roaima The OP said he knew about that and wasn't interested. He wanted to know how to `filter output through filters`

Comment: He was also under the misapprehension that globbing is handled by commands themselves rather than by the shell.

Comment: @roaima Maybe. But things like grep work for other stuff as well, like `cat /etc/passwd | egrep ":/home"`. I'm sure there are better examples. It's not the best question, though I can understand why such a question could be asked. Piping output through filters as he asked is something we do all the time.

Comment: `egrep ':/home' /etc/passwd` would be sufficient. But yes, pipelines are an important (if not essential) part of the Unix offering.